# Do I have to use my personal fb account to manage my work's app?

Tags: facebook-apps, accounts

I need to create an app on a website for a non-profit that uploads information to their Facebook page. I've read that businesses can't create apps so I'm really lost. Is it necessary for me as a developer to open a personal account to manage this app for the non-profit? This is more of a business thing and not about me personally, so why does it need to be tied to me? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apps need to be tied to at least one developer account - you don't have to enter much personal information or use it for anything else besides the app if you don't want to. Assuming this is client work you're going to eventually transfer ownership of the app to someone at the non-profit for stewardship anyway, and besides you'll need at least one Facebook account to test that the app works properly.

Unless ofc I'm misunderstanding your question...